# What should be the clearance hole size for mounting a hub on a motor shaft?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, machining, drilling

I have a motor with an 8mm shaft diameter. I'm trying to make my own hub for direct mount driving a wheel. What diameter hole size should I drill for the hub's shaft which couples with the motor shaft? Would these be the same standards as clearance hole drillings for screws? For example, an M3 screw has a suggested close fit drill size of 3.2mm and a normal fit drill size of 3.4mm. Should I drill an 8.2mm diameter then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a sliding fit or transition. 0.2mm clearance is far too much, H7g6 sounds about right, hole is 0.005-0.029 mm bigger than the shaft. You'll need to use a reamer or a D bit.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the term sliding fit or H7g6